# How to create a zone with specific IAM permissions in Cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-dns

I'm getting an error trying to set DNS zone permissions. I'm following [official instruction](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones/iam-per-resource-zones) for a feature released in GA on Dec 5th 2022 "Cloud DNS per resource IAM permissions". I'm trying to resolve issue described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791366/google-cloud-dns-how-to-restrict-permission-just-to-one-zone-for-acme-challeng). Unfortunately I always get `You don't have permission to edit the permissions of the selected resource` despite of the fact my account seem to have suitable roles.

What I did was:

- assign "DNS Administrator" role to my account in IAM (see: [my IAM roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRYMn.png))
- create a public managed zone in Cloud DNS
- tick the check-box for the zone and click on "Permissions" button at the top

Result is this [permissions warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNdc1.png).
Still I believe my account is granted "DNS Administrator" role as suggested in [the official instruction](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones/iam-per-resource-zones).

Is this something related to IAM roles/permissions or Cloud DNS issue?

*Edit*: do not know how to get it working with DNS roles but when assigned `Owner` role I was able to edit DNS zone permissions.

Comment: Exact same problem here